# Internal API call using axios

Tags: node.js, api, vue.js, axios, frontend

I have two node instances, backend on express with MongoDB on port 5000 and Frontend on VueJs on port 8080.

**My goal is to make an API call straight from frontend server, so that the user does not have the access to the DB.**

Currently I have this configuration which works perfectly on localhost, but does not white accessing from any other machine.

Component used on Home.vue:

```
import AxiosModule from "@/middleware/axiosmodule.js";
(...)
 methods:{
        /* eslint-disable no-console */
        fetchData(){
            AxiosModule
                .get("/data")
                .then(response => {
                    this.values = response.data;
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        },
```

AxiosModule:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/api/",
    headers:{
        "Content-type": "application/json",
    },
});
```

At localhost:5000/api/data there is an array of objects.

When accessing :8080 from local network, there is 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED' message in console regarding connecting to :5000/api/data which, I presume, suggests that the actual call for API comes from the client, not the server (I have only 8080 port open on my router).

Therefore, as I understand I have two options: make the API call internally and block access to port 5000 or implement [some sort of authorization](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#creating-an-instance).

Of course if thee is any better way of doing this, please let me know. Thanks is advance.

Comment: Obvious question but are you linking the to IP correctly? so Ipconfig ipv4 and then the port after that aka https:192.168.0.xx:3000

Comment: @ThomasMorris The IP address was correct, but my approach wasn't. After talking with a friend who often works with APIs, I've come to understand that I need to leave the backend open to users and require JWT authorization on certain parts. Thanks for your response anyways.